# How to deploy a saved ml model built using Spark-ml library in java

Tags: java, data-science, apache-spark-ml, machine-learning-model

I have built an multi-class classification model using spark ml and java. I need suggestions on how to deploy the saved classification model locally in order to consume and classify new datasets. Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps: https://towardsdatascience.com/there-are-two-very-different-ways-to-deploy-ml-models-heres-both-ce2e97c7b9b1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do we have something similar to this for apache spark and java ?